# The final local variable connection cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have used "content" string to fetch the data from website and also in facebook integration to share the current page's data(content) on the wall,  I attempted to add final in front of the declaration but that throws the following error within bundle... The final local variable connection cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment.
How can i correct this?

```
private String headerContent;
  public String html,content;
     private Facebook mFacebook;
        private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    private Bundle bundle;
    public String description,title;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        //@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bundle params = new Bundle();



            mFacebook.dialog(Singlemenuitem.this, "feed",params,
               (DialogListener) new SampleDialogListener());            


              }

    });

    if (bundle != null)

    {

        headerContent = bundle.getString("Header_Content");
content=bundle.getString("content");

        url = bundle.getString("url");
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the variable `final`. `final` variables must be initialized either with an initializer expression or in the constructor(s). You are assigning to it in `onCreate`, which is too late in the lifecycle of the object.

Instead of making the variable `public`, make it `private` and provide an accessor method.

```
private String content;

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}
```

Comment: Where should i paste this code public String getContent() {
    return content;
}... m getting same error ted@Ted Hopp

Comment: @DivyaJehova - It should be a method in the class that you posted in your question. If you're getting the same error, you must be still declaring it `final`. You must remove the `final`. (Making the variable `private` will also prevent changes to the variable from outside the class.)